# Dereferencing an array from an array of arrays in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have various subroutines that give me arrays of arrays. I have tested them separately and somehow when i write my main routine, I fail to make the program recognize my arrays. I know it's a problem of dereferencing, or at least i suspect it heavily.

The code is a bit long but I'll try to explain it:

```
my @leaderboard=@arrarraa; #an array of arrays
my $parentmass=$spect[$#spect]; #scalar

while (scalar @leaderboard>0) {
        for my $i(0..(scalar @leaderboard-1)) {
        my $curref=$leaderboard[$i]; #the program says here that there is an uninitialized value. But I start with a list of 18 elements.
        my @currentarray=@$curref; #then i try to dereference the array
        my $w=sumaarray (@currentarray);
        if ($w==$parentmass) {
            if (defined $Leader[0]) {
                my $sc1=score (@currentarray);
                my $sc2=score (@Leader);
                if ($sc1>$sc2) {
                    @Leader=@currentarray;
                }

            }
            else {@Leader=@currentarray;}
        }
        elsif ($w>$parentmass) {splice @leaderboard,$i,1;} #here i delete the element if it doesn't work. I hope it's done correctly.

    }
    my $leadref= cut (@leaderboard); #here i take the first 10 scores of the AoAs
    @leaderboard = @$leadref;
    my $leaderef=expand (@leaderboard); #then i expand the AoAs by one term
    @leaderboard= @$leaderef;            #and i should end with a completely different list to work with in the while loop
}
```

So I don't know how to dereference the AoAs correctly. The output of the program says:

"Use of uninitialized value $curref in concatenation (.) or string at C:\Algorithms\22cyclic\cyclospectrumsub.pl line 183.
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at C:\Algorithms\22cyclic\cyclospectrumsub.pl line 184."

I would appreciate enormously any insight or recommendation.

Comment: The error is not happening where you indicate; that line will never generate that error.  Figure out where the error is really happening.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the `splice` that modifies the list while it is being processed. By using the `0..(scalar @leaderboard-1)` you set up the range of elements to process at the beginning, but when some elements are removed by the `splice`, the list ends up shorter than that and once `$i` runs off the end of the modified list you get undefined references.

A quick fix would be to use

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @leaderboard; $i++)
```

although that's neither very idiomatic nor efficient.
Note that doing something like `$i < @leaderboard` or `@leaderboard-1` already provides scalar context for the array variable, so you don't need the `scalar()` call, it does nothing here.

I'd probably use something like

```
my @result;
while(my $elem = shift @leaderboard) {
    ...
    if ($w==$parentmass) {
        # do more stuff
        push @result, $elem;
    }
}
```

So instead of deleting from the original list, all elements would be taken off the original and only the successful (by whatever criterion) ones included in the result.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two things going on here

- You're removing all arrays from `@leaderboard` whose `sumaarray` is *greater than* `$parentmass`
- You're putting in `@Leader` the array with the highest `score` of all the arrays in `@leaderboard` whose `sumaarray` is *equal to* `$parentmass`

I'm unclear whether that's correct. You don't seem to handle the case where `sumaarray` is *less than* `$parentmass` at all. But that can be written very simply by using `grep` together with the `max_by` function from the [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) module

```
use List::UtilsBy 'max_by';


my $parentmass = $spect[-1];

my @leaderboard = grep { sumaarray(@$_) <= $parentmass } @arrarraa;

my $leader = max_by { score(@$_) }
        grep { sumaarray(@$_) == $parentmass }
        @leaderboard;
```

I'm sure this could be made a lot neater if I understood the intention of your algorithm; especially how those elements with a `sumarray` of less that `$parentmass`